# 502 Bad Gateway with nginx inside docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I am facing a problem with reverse proxy regarding Docker services.

When I try to access http://website.com its Ok, when I try to access http://website.com:2086 its also Ok but when I try to access http://website.com/api its getting 502 Bad Gateway.

Summary: location / ... is working location / api ... is not working

Any clue?

My frontend docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Here's my nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com;


   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

   location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:2086;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }}
```

My backend docker-compose.yml(related to the api)

```
services:
web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bin/rails s -p 2086 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
    - "2086:2086"
    depends_on:
    - redis
redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
    - redis_data:/data
```

volumes:
redis_data:
bundle:

The log I've got

2023-12-21 15:45:17 vox-web-1 | 2023/12/21 18:45:17 [error] 29#29: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.240.1, server: website.com, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "192.168.240.2:2086/api", host: "localhost" 2023-12-21 15:45:17 vox-web-1 | 192.168.240.1 - - [21/Dec/2023:18:45:17 +0000] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.0.0" "-" –